# How to fix my current MIPS 32 SCP Register File's clock/data errors

Tags: verilog, clock, iverilog

I'm building a Single Cycle Processor for a class assignment in Verilog and I can't seem to get the correct output with my test bench. I've got everything wired correctly and it is producing zeros for the first half of my test bench like it should, but once I start putting data in, it stays at zero. So I know my reset and clock works, but somewhere in the write section, I am overlooking something. I could use a fresh set of eyes and any help is appreciated. TIA.

RegisterFile.v:

```
module registerfile(read1, read2, writeto, writedat, writeenable, out1, out2, clock, reset);

input [4:0] read1;
input [4:0] read2;
input [4:0] writeto;
input [31:0] writedat;
input writeenable, clock, reset;

output [31:0] out1, out2;
// 32 bit registers x 32

reg [31:0] RF[31:0];
reg [31:0] out1;
reg [31:0] out2;

integer i;

always @(posedge reset)
begin
    for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        RF[i] <= 0;
    out1 <= 32'h00000000;
    out2 <= 32'h00000000;
end

always @(posedge clock)
begin
    if (writeenable)
        RF[writeto] <= writedat;

    out1 <= RF[read1];
    out2 <= RF[read2];
end

endmodule
```

RegisterFile_tb.v:

```
module registerfile_tb ();

reg [4:0] read1;
reg [4:0] read2;
wire [31:0] out1;
wire [31:0] out2;
reg [4:0] writeto;
reg [31:0] writedat;
reg writeenable;
reg clock;
reg reset;

registerfile DUT(read1, read2, writeto, writedat, writeenable, out1, out2, clock, reset);

initial
begin
    clock <= 1;
    reset <= 1;
    #21 reset <= 0;
    #100;

    read1 <= 5'b0;
    read2 <= 5'b0;
    writeto <= 5'b00101;
    writedat <= 32'd0;
    writeenable <= 1;

    #100;
    #21 read1 <= 5'b11010;
    #21 read2 <= 5'b00101;
    #21 read1 <= 5'b00001;
    #21 writedat <= 32'd1; //
    #21 read2 <= 5'b11111;
    #21 read1 <= 5'b01010;
    #21 read2 <= 5'b01110;
end

always @(read1 or read2)
    #21 $display("| read1 = %d | read2 = %d | out1 = %d | out2 = %d |", read1, read2, out1, out2);

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

Your clock is not toggling. There should be an `always #10 clk = !clk;` in your test bench (you may want a different delay).

Your display statement is a bit odd. Consider changing it to a monitor and move it near the top of the initial block.

FYI. Your code will not synthesis. To me synthesizable a register must be assigned by only one always block. You have separate blocks for the clock and reset. To have asynchronous reset use the structure below. For synchronous reset (required for most FPGAs) then omit the `or posedge reset`

```
always @(posedge clock or posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset) begin
        for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            RF[i] <= 0;
        out1 <= 32'h00000000;
        out2 <= 32'h00000000;
    end
    else begin
        if (writeenable)
            RF[writeto] <= writedat;
        out1 <= RF[read1];
        out2 <= RF[read2];
    end
end
```